# Resolve enum template parameters at run-time

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to come up with a piece of logic that takes multiple enums and determine a struct type and its corresponding size to pass to a third-party component, and I am considering to use traits to solve this issue in a clean way:

A brute force solution (using one enum) looks something like this:

```
typedef enum FOO_TYPE
{
    FOO_TYPE_0 = 0,
    FOO_TYPE_1 = 1,
    ...
} FOO_TYPE;

switch (m_foo)
{
    case (FOO_TYPE_0):
    {
        FOO_0 Foo = {};
        UINT size = sizeof(Foo);
        m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&Foo, size);
    }
    break;

    case (FOO_TYPE_1):
    ...
}
```

I considered using traits to solve this issue by defining specialization for each FOO_TYPE, but hit the issue during compilation because I am picking the specializations of the templates at run-time instead of at compile-time. However, it's not immediately obvious to me how I could resolve this without incurring the cost of the switch statement (which grows very quickly when you consider multiple enum types) above. If anyone has ideas, please let me know.

```
template <FOO_TYPE FooType> 
struct FooTraits;

template <>
struct FooTraits<FOO_TYPE_0>
{
    typedef FOO_0 FooStruct;
};

{
    typedef FooTraits<m_foo> FooTraitsType; <== THIS USAGE CAUSES COMPILATION ERRORS
    FooTraitsType::FooStruct Foo = {};
    UINT size = sizeof(FooTraitsType::FooStruct);
    m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&Foo, size);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: not possible? you must have a switch statement unless you know the type in compile time

Comment: You need to use the templated class at the point where the type is known. When only the runtime `m_foo` integer is known, it's way too late.

You're not telling where does this `m_foo` come from, and what problem you're trying to solve. I don't know what you need the enums for. If all you have is an instance of a non-polymorphic type, you can use `sizeof()` to determine its size and pass it to the third-party component.

Comment: In practice, there are multiple enum types that factor into which struct is used, and some of these enums (i.e. m_foo) can come from third-party components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this at run-time using templates, but you do have some other options you can use localise the changes.

My preference would be to use polymorphism:

```
class Foo {
  static Foo* createFoo(FOO_TYPE type) {
  switch(type) {
     case FOO_TYPE_0:
       return new FooType0();
     case FOO_TYPE_1:
       return new FooType1();
  }
  virtual void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty)=0;
}

class FooType0 : public Foo {
   void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty) {
      FOO_0 Foo = {};
      UINT size = sizeof(Foo);
      m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&Foo, size);
   } 
}

class FooType1 : public Foo {
   void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty) {
      FOO_1 Foo = {};
      UINT size = sizeof(Foo);
      m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&Foo, size);
   } 
}
```

Your switch block would then become:

```
// Note this leaks ... see below for non-leaking version.
createFoo(m_foo)->callFunction(m_thirdParty);
```

Now there's some ugly duplication in each of the FooTypeX classes, so you can remove that with templatization:

```
class Foo {
  static Foo* createFoo(FOO_TYPE type) {
  switch(type) {
     case FOO_TYPE_0:
       return new FooX<FOO_1>();
     case FOO_TYPE_1:
       return new FooX<FOO_2>();
  }
  virtual void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty)=0;
}

class FooX<BaseStruct> : public Foo {
   void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty) {
      BaseStruct foo = {};
      UINT size = sizeof(foo);
      m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&foo, size);
   } 
} 

// A bit of a hack to prevent leaking. In real code you may want to 
// handle ownership differently.
std::unique_ptr<Foo>(createFoo(m_foo))->callFunction(m_thirdParty);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be
static Foo* createFoo(FOO_TYPE type) 
instead of:
static Foo createFoo(FOO_TYPE type)

Comment: Indeed it should, and its fixed.

Comment: This leaks memory, doesn't it?

Comment: @C.R. Yep, you can handle that by assigning to a temporary `unique_ptr`. Other solutions might be to provide a dumb uncopyable wrapper, or to return const references to singleton instances (since `FooX<Y>` is stateless).

Comment: I noticed that you didn't make a virtual destructor for Foo, which means that when the unique_ptr destroys Foo, it wouldn't invoke FooX<Y>'s destructor. Is that OK because FooX<Y> is stateless? Even if that's the case, I am inclined to just make a virtual destructor anyways to avoid errors in the future when FooX<Y> is no longer stateless.