# How to limit to stack allocations for polymorphic solution of resolving types

Tags: c++, memory, polymorphism

This is an extension of a question I have previously asked: [Resolve enum template parameters at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644248/resolve-enum-template-parameters-at-run-time). For convenience, I have pasted a solution proposed by Michael here:

```
class Foo {
  static Foo* createFoo(FOO_TYPE type) {
  switch(type) {
     case FOO_TYPE_0:
       return new FooX<FOO_1>();
     case FOO_TYPE_1:
       return new FooX<FOO_2>();
  }
  virtual void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty)=0;
}

class FooX<BaseStruct> : public Foo {
   void callFunction(ThridParty thirdParty) {
      BaseStruct foo = {};
      UINT size = sizeof(foo);
      m_thirdParty->CallFunction(&foo, size);
   } 
} 

// A bit of a hack to prevent leaking. In real code you may want to 
// handle ownership differently.
std::unique_ptr<Foo>(createFoo(m_foo))->callFunction(m_thirdParty);
```

I was wondering if there's a way to address this issue while keep the memory allocation on the stack, instead of on the heap? I am asking because this helper class will be used many times so I'd like to not incur the performance cost of multiple heap allocations (i.e. my understanding is that stack allocation can be much faster). Also, if the solution is limited to stack allocations, I think I wouldn't need to use things like unique_pointers to free the memory, and it'd be automatically freed upon going out of scope.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a couple of static `FooX<>` instances and only return a const reference to a matching one from `createFoo()` (aptly renamed)?

Comment: Agree that this is a duplicate. However, I am not sure how to mark it accordingly. If there are moderators, please mark this as a dupe.