# Storage of function pointer in polymorphic class without explicit template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am trying to create a helper class to abstract invoking function pointers. With feedback from others on SO, I am using a polymorphic class to achieve this (shown below). Templates are also used to reduce code duplication.

```
typedef void(*PFNFOO1) (int);
typedef void(*PFNFOO2) (double);
typedef void(*PFNBAR1) (long);
typedef void(*PFNBAR2) (float);

typedef struct FOO_TABLE
{
    PFNFOO1 pfnFoo1;
    PFNFOO2 pfnFoo2;
} FOO_TABLE;

typedef struct BAR_TABLE
{
    PFNBAR1 pfnBar1;
    PFNBAR2 pfnBar2;
} BAR_TABLE;

enum TABLE_TYPE
{
    TYPE_FOO = 0,
    TYPE_BAR = 1,
};

template <typename T>
class FooBarImpl : public FooBarBase
{
public:  
    // GetFunc is created to centralize needed validation before function is invoked
    void* GetFunc(size_t funcOffset)
    {
        // do some validation
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_FooBarTable + funcOffset);
    }

    void* GetpfnFoo1() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnFoo1)); }
    void* GetpfnFoo2() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnFoo2)); }
    void* GetpfnBar1() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnBar1)); }
    void* GetpfnBar2() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnBar2)); }

    T* m_FooBarTable;
};

class FooBarBase
{
public:
    static FooBarBase* CreateFooBar(TABLE_TYPE tableType)
    {
        switch(tableType)
        {               
            case (TYPE_FOO) :
            {
                return new FooBarImpl<FOO_TABLE>();
            }
            break;

            case (TYPE_BAR) :
            {
                return new FooBarImpl<BAR_TABLE>();
            }
            break;
        }                

    }

    virtual void* GetpfnFoo1() = 0;
    virtual void* GetpfnFoo2() = 0;
    virtual void* GetpfnBar1() = 0;
    virtual void* GetpfnBar2() = 0;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        FooBarBase *pFooBar = FooBarBase::CreateFooBar(TYPE_FOO);
        // Initialize Foo table
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<PFNFOO1>(pFooBar->GetpfnFoo1());
        int parameter = 1;
        p(parameter);
    }

    {
        FooBarBase *pFooBar = FooBarBase::CreateFooBar(TYPE_FOO);
        // Initialize Bar table
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<PFNBAR2>(pFooBar->GetpfnBar2());
        float parameter = 1.0f;
        p(parameter);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This is currently giving me complication errors as "C2039: 'pfnBar1' : is not a member of 'FOO_TABLE'" which makes sense because one of the implicit template specialization will try to do "offsetof(FOO_TABLE, pfnBar1)," which isn't allowed. I have two questions. First, I am wondering what's the best way to address this error. I think I can possibly address this by providing explicit template specializations for FooBarImpl and FooBarImpl, but I'd like to avoid doing that because it means that if I were to add a new table type later, I'd have to add another specialization. Also, it increases code duplication. Therefore, if there's a way to fix this issue without explicit template specialization, please let m know.

For my second question, if explicit template specialization cannot be avoided, I have also tried this:

```
class FooBarBase;

template <typename T>
class FooBarImpl : public FooBarBase
{
};

template <>
class FooBarImpl<FOO_TABLE> : public FooBarBase
{
public:
    typedef FOO_TABLE T;

    // GetFunc is created to centralize needed validation before function is invoked
    void* GetFunc(size_t funcOffset)
    {
        // do some validation
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_FooBarTable + funcOffset);
    }

    void* GetpfnFoo1() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnFoo1)); }
    void* GetpfnFoo2() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnFoo2)); }

    T* m_FooBarTable;
};

template<>
class FooBarImpl<BAR_TABLE> : public FooBarBase
{
public:
    typedef BAR_TABLE T;

    // GetFunc is created to centralize needed validation before function is invoked
    void* GetFunc(size_t funcOffset)
    {
        // do some validation
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_FooBarTable + funcOffset);
    }

    void* GetpfnBar1() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnBar1)); }
    void* GetpfnBar2() { return GetFunc(offsetof(T, pfnBar2)); }

    T* m_FooBarTable;
};
```

But for some reason, I keep getting this error "error C2504: 'FooBarBase' : base class undefined" even if it was working fine before I specialized the templates.

If anyone has ideas about these 2 questions, I'd really appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: "helper class to abstract invoking function pointers" - you're not abstracting anything... your point of client usage assumes a specific runtime type and `reinterpret_cast`s so it can recover a specific member.  It's effectively an unsafe attempt to do what `dynamic_cast<>` trivially allows, but even then it's pointless because there's no unifying base class behaviour justifying the inheritance.  Why not just create a struct with a union of FOO_TABLE and BAR_TABLE and an int to tell you which one's meaningful?  Your extra code's not buying anything but obfuscation.

Comment: The main point of doing is so that when the function tables are created, we can enforce strict validation and loose validation when the function pointers are invoked. It's hard to illustrate that using a small self-contained example, so please bear with me.

Comment: Also, these function pointers are called many times, and this saves having a bunch of duplicate switch statements to determine which table the function pointers are supposed to be invoked from.

Comment: And this can't be done with a simple wrapperfunction? I'm asking because I try to understand, which part of your code can be changed, without breaking your usecase.

Comment: Also i don't see how this can save any switch statements

Comment: Can you post the link to the original question that inspired this design?

Comment: Sure, it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644248/resolve-enum-template-parameters-at-run-time.

Comment: The switch statement is saved because the work to convert run-time types to compile-time types (useful for allowing template usage to minimize duplicates) only has to happen at CreateFooBar, instead of everytime you need to invoke an function pointer.

Comment: "The switch is saved"... isn't `FooBarBase *pFooBar = FooBarBase::CreateFooBar(TYPE_FOO); auto p = reinterpret_cast<PFNBAR2>(pFooBar->GetpfnBar2());`, followed by the function pointer usage, considerably more hassle than say `if (Foo* p = dynamic_cast<Foo>(pFooBar)) p(my_int);` (assuming an `operator()(int)`) or say `if (pFooBar->is(FOO)) { Foo* p = (Foo*)pFooBar; p(my_int); }`?  There is no "work to convert run-time types to compile-time"... however it's done you just need a runtime type *recognition* branching to some appropriate code.  `virtual` repeats per call, switching can be grouped.